# How do I create a croppable banner image in uiimagepickercontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When I present a UIImagePickerController, I want the user to be able to crop a 7.8 ratio for the banner that the user wants to import from their photo library.

This question is similar to many questions relating to creating custom crop rects built to work with UIImagePickerController but all the answers point to outdated libraries or libraries with too much complexity. I want something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var newImage: UIImage

    if picker.sourceType == .camera {
        if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            // save photo
        }
    }

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad && picker.sourceType == .photoLibrary {
        if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
        }
    } else {
        if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
        } else if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
        }
    }

    // logic to manipulate image
    print("image size: \(newImage.size)")

    let newHeight = 100 // change to preferred height
    let scale = 7.8
    let newWidth = newImage.size.width

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

    newImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    print("image size: \(newImage.size)")

    // add logic here
}
```